# get the row with the highest value in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to get the highest value but group by another field on the same table
ex:

seqid  + fileid + name

```
1  |    1 | n1
2  |    1 | n2
3  |    2 | n3
4  |    3 | n4
5  |    3 | n5
```

the result must be

seqid  + fileid + name

```
2  |    1 | n2
3  |    2 | n3
5  |    3 | n5
```

note: all the field must be display like using select *
I'll appreciate any help.tnx

Comment: a little formatting would definitely help..

Comment: group by fileid and the seqid is for the max value

Comment: What's wrong with the `MAX()` function?

Comment: i'll try the max but.. I cannot get the result I want.. may there's lacking in my query.. I think I need to use a (select max(seqid)) inside the select *.. then group by fileid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    Table t INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  fileid,
                    MAX(seqid) Maxseqid
            FROM    Table
            GROUP BY    fileid
        ) m ON  t.fileid = m.fileid
            AND t.seqid = m.Maxseqid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT seqid, fileid, name
FROM tbl JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(seqid) maxSeq, fileid fileid
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY fileid
    ) tg ON tml.seqid = tg.maxSeq AND tbl.fileid = tg.fileid
```

Answer (score 0):

Describe exactly what you need, provide bigger table, and result table, also I dont get it what you mean at all highest value but group by another field, highest value of what column?

in your result you mention 4|3|n5, why not 5|3|n5 if you say Highest ?

ok so you edited it..

looks fairly simple something like

```
     select seqid, filed,name from table t1 join 
(select max(seqid) seqid from table group by fileid) as t2 on t2.seqid=t1.seqid
```

if seqid is PK you dont need anything but PK i dont get why would you want to join on 2 fields instead of just PK