# SQL selecting multiple last rows

Tags: mysql, row

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get the row with the highest value in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407030/get-the-row-with-the-highest-value-in-mysql)

Is there a way to select multiple `last rows`?

So there's a `version_id` column that I want to use to select the last entries.

And there's another column that is the `actual_id`.

I would like to pull out a list of `actual_ids` based on the latest versions of them.

`Last()` function doesn't work. I heard that `order by version_id desc limit 1` is a way to go about doing this, but it limits any result set I get to only 1 row.

Is there a way to go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

so `order by version_id desc` will give you the data set you want.  Then the limit clause will give you the amount of results you want.

and you can have any number there not just 1.  You can do limit 5, limit 1000 or whatever you want.

```
order by version_id desc limit 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get the most recent version of each actual id:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select t.actual_id, max(version_id) as maxv
      from t
      group by t.actual_id
     ) mt
     on t.actual_id = mt.actual_id and t.version = mt.maxv
```

Comment: thanks Gordon! This was extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, I would do it simply like

```
select top n actual_id, version_id from ActualVersion order by version_id desc
```

you can replace n by the number of top records you want to choose.

Comment: Since OP mentions `LIMIT` in his question, I'd infer that he's not using SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks Joe, just re-read and I seem to have missed that

Answer (score 0):

You can change `1` to (for example) `5`:

```
order by version_id desc limit 5
```