# MYSQL Get highest value from duplicates entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I failed to build a complex query. See my results example under my query. 
I want that my query return only the entry with the highest date (2014-02-19 16:25:11) where program_id, name and type are the same and where the value is different.

```
SELECT
    LPAD(convert( master_program.program_id USING utf8),
            5,
            '00000') AS program_id,
    rate.name,
    rate.type,
    rate.value
FROM
    master,
    master_program,
    programs,
    rate_group,
    rate
WHERE
    master.id = master_program.master_id
        AND master_program.program_id = programs.id
        AND rate_group.master_id = master.id
        AND rate_group.id = rate.rate_group_id
        AND master.is_deleted = 0
        AND rate_group.is_deleted = 0
        AND master.is_payout = 0
ORDER BY program_id, name
```

---- RESULTS EXAMPLE ----

```
program_id | name    | type | value  | last_modified_date
­­­­­­­­­­­­-------------------------------------------------------------
-> 00470   | Default | PPL  | 4.6900 | "2014-02-17 16:13:16" (same but different value)
-> 00470   | Default | PPL  | 0.0000 | "2014-02-19 16:25:11" (same but different value)
00470      | G1      | PPL  | 5.0000 | "2014-02-19 16:25:11"
00470      | G2      | PPL  | 3.5000 | "2014-02-19 16:25:11"
00015      | Default | PPL  | 0.0000 | "2014-02-19 16:25:11"
00015      | Default | PPL  | 0.0000 | "2014-02-19 16:25:11"
```

Thanks for your time and for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [get the row with the highest value in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407030/get-the-row-with-the-highest-value-in-mysql)

Comment: A dozen questions identical to this have been asked here today alone. It gets a bit tedious. Of course, it doesn't help that others keep providing incorrect answers.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your select statement for the `last_modified_date` field, but in any case, change your select statement to:

```
SELECT
    LPAD(convert( master_program.program_id USING utf8),
            5,
            '00000') AS program_id,
    rate.name,
    rate.type,
    rate.value,
    MAX(table.last_modified_date)
WHERE....
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted the highest value. There's no suggestion that this concurs with the latest date.